# Displaying multidimensional array from a posted form

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

Hi I am trying to display information from a form, the number of question and number of choices are dynamically generated by the user. The form is as follows:

```
<input name='questions[]' type='text' value='question 1' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 1' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 2' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 3' /><br/>
<input name='questions[]' type='text' value='question 2' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[2-1][]' type='text' value='option 1' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[2-1][]' type='text' value='option 2' /><br/>
   <input name='choice[2-1][]' type='text' value='option 3' /><br/>
```

etc...

I have had no problems with creating the code to generate the form, my problem lies in the displaying the information which the uses puts into the form.

So far I have tried using a foreach loop to display the question then another foreach loop to display the choices. I have also tried using the count() then using a for loop to count through the number of choices and output them that way, with no success.

My problem is that when I try to display the choices, they are all displayed before the next question is displayed and then all the choices are displayed again, before the script moves onto the next question and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intended outcome is not very clear, but here is an idea of what I think you are looking to do.

```
$i=1;
foreach ($questions as $question){
echo $question;
echo "<br />";
foreach($choice[$i.'-1'] as $choices){
echo '-'.$choices.'<br />';
}
echo "<br />";
$i++;
}
```

Based off your `<form>` code, when it is posted, you would have arrays like -

```
$questions = array('question 1', 'question 2');
$choice['1-1']= array('option 1','option 2','option 3');
$choice['2-1']= array('option 1','option 2','option 3');
```

So using the `foreach` on those arrays, you would get an output of -

```
question 1
-option 1
-option 2
-option 3

question 2
-option 1
-option 2
-option 3
```

You can see a phpfiddle at - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i4f-k7w

Comment: thanks for your help on that. I knew I was close :D I'd almost given up.